# validate form fields before uploading file (Blueimp jquery file upload)

Tags: forms, angularjs, blueimp

i have been working blueimp file upload (angularjs version), i wanted to validate form before uploading file say i have a form that contains Name and Description and i want these ones must be provided before uploading file.

i wanted to use angular form validation up to now i have tried this code

```
$scope.$on('fileuploadsubmit', function (event, files) {
    if (filename) { // its a formfield 
        _uploadTemp.loadingIcon = true;
        $.each(files.files, function (index, file) {
            files.formData = {
                file_rename: file.name,
                templateName: _uploadTemp.name
            };
        });
    }
    else {
        form.submit = true
    }
});
```

doing this one shows me an error on file name but also submit file to server . is there any way from which i can stop file uploading and can show error??

any help will be appreciated , just want to mention that i m using BLUEIMP FILE UPLOAD Angularjs version

Answer (score 0):

I have created a directive exactly for this purpose [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rq6fnmffQMIcdVGGyeC3). The code i had pasted there is just to give you an idea of how the directive should be. Sorry for not putting a working version. If i get time today/tomorrow I will make it working. It would take 1-2 hours to remove all dependencies. But this should give you and idea and get you going.

what i had implemented there is:

> 1. required validation
> 2. extension validation
> 3. non-empty file
> 4. make form dirty/invalid
> 5. pretty select/remove buttons
> 6. get file size in object
> 7. custom validations using ui validate

specify validations in javascript

```
$scope.fileValidations = {
                extension: "xlsx",
                required: true,
            };


<cs-file-upload ng-model="selected.filename" file-info="selected.fileInfo"
                        validations="fileValidations"></cs-file-upload>
```

i am using angular-file-upload module for this, which should work more or less similar to blueimp.

I will surely try to put working version by tomorrow...